Why does subsonic flow decelerate in diverging nozzle and supersonic flow accelerate in a diverging nozzle?
-Why does the pressure decrease in the converging section for subsonic speeds and the speed increases?
-Why does the pressure increase in the diverging section for subsonic speeds and the speed decreases?
-Why does the pressure increase in the converging section for supersonic speeds and the speed decreases?
-Why does the pressure decrease in diverging section for supersonic speeds and the speed increases?
I understand why all this theoretically happens just based on the equations for mass conservation, Bernoulli's theorem, compressible flow, etc. but does anyone have a good physical intuitive explanation?
